# Is there another thread (apart from the main thread) which keeps on polling on the async operation in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, multithreading, asynchronous, event-loop

I understand that Javascript is single threaded and a event queue is maintained in order to handle events in a FIFO order. If the main thread fires an async operation and the callback is added to the event queue, is there any other background thread which keeps polling on the async operation and notifies the event queue to execute the callback?

Comment: The means by which events "happen" is not something that's specified by the language itself. It's part of the runtime environment.

Comment: …and polling is a pretty dumb technique, so it's not used in runtime implementations.

Comment: Long polling is a pretty standard technique. It was in fact the only technique till sockets came around.